# Inequality problem about sides of a triangle and the semiperimeter

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, inequality, triangles

Let $a,b,c$ the sides of a triangle and $s$ be the semi perimeter. Then show that 
$$
              a^2+b^2+c^2 > \frac{36}{35}(a^2+\frac{abc}{s})
$$
I tried it doing in many ways using some changes but cannot help my cause.

Comment: inspite of voting it down...can you solve it...den vote it down @ Test123

Comment: This is not a homework help site.

Comment: @Test123 isn't necessarily the one who downvoted, and as far as I can tell, he's only the editor.

Comment: @Awesome - this may not be a site that was designed for homework help, but asking homework questions are fine.

Comment: On that note, @soumajitdas, I would recommend providing some more detail about what you have tried so far, and where exactly you're stuck.

Comment: some effort should be shown, I guess...

Comment: I tried triangle inequality...AM-GM inequality but cannot find any idea.....

Comment: Maybe Cauchy scharwz lemma ?

Comment: cant find suitable components a & b for applying cauchy schrawz...

Comment: $a^2+b^2+c^2\geqslant (a+b+c)^2/3$

Comment: I just love proving inequalities.

Answer (score 4):

The inequality seems really loose to me, and this approach shows that it is indeed loose. ( which makes me somewhat doubt the inequality is what we want to show)

We want to show that

$$ 35 b^2 +35 c^2 > a^2 + 36 abc/s .$$

We have $b+c > a$ and so $ 2s > 2a $ and so $abc/s < bc $. We will show that

$$ 35 b^2 +35 c^2 > a^2 + 36 bc .$$

This is true because $a < b+c $ so $a^2 < 2 b^2 + 2c^2$, which gives us

$$ 18(b-c)^2 +17 b^2 +17 c^2 > a^2$$

---

In fact, with the above, we can show that

$$
              a^2+b^2+c^2 > \frac{6}{5}(a^2+\frac{abc}{s})
$$

the 'equality condition' occurs when $a=2b=2c$.

Comment: but its 36/35 @ calvin lin.

Comment: @soumajitdas he has proved your case first, and $36/35 < 6/5$, so the last one is stronger.

Comment: @soumajit note that I only proved 36/35 and not 6/5. The latter is easily deduced using my method.